# Necessity of “Progn” Becoming “Special Operator”

Tags: common-lisp

If `progn` is NOT a *special operator*, it could be defined as *macro* like this:

```
(defmacro progn (&rest body)
  `(let ()
     ,@body))
```

I guess that `defmacro`'s definition may have used some `progn`s, but it only needs to substitute `(let () ...)`s for those `(progn ...)`s.

Less *special operator*s, more elegant.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer concerns Common Lisp, not Lisp in general.]

`progn` must be special at least because it must be handled specially at top-level.  In particular when compiling a file containing, say

```
(defun foo ...)
(progn
  (defun bar ...)
  (progn
    ...))
```

Then the forms inside the `progn`s are at top-level and are recognised as such by the compiler.  In contrast in a file containing

```
(defun foo ...)
(let ()
  (defun bar ...))
```

The forms inside the `let` are *not* at top-level, and are therefore not recognised as such by the compiler.  This matters quite a lot in some cases, and it means that your definition of `progn` is not correct and that it is not in fact possible to define `progn` without resorting to `progn` in the definition.

However, it clearly is the case that CL has more special operators than it strictly needs.  For instance you can easily make `let` out of `lambda` in the obvious way, so `let` is not really needed.  I don't think anyone ever argued that CL's set of special operators was strictly minimal, because CL was not designed to be a strictly minimal Lisp.

Comment: If CL hadn't `progn`, it would have said an empty let like `(let () ...)` is toplevel too, or something like that; having lambda and let be unified requires the compilers/interpreters to distinguish the different cases anyway (the lambda is/isn't escaping the scope, etc). So in fact it is actually better to have distinct operators if unifying their semantic is too cumbersome

Comment: @coredump This is not the right forum, but having a special case for `(let () ...)` would be hideous, as (apart from other horrors) you'd need `(let (x) (declare (ignore x)) ...)` to do what `(let () ...)` now does.  Nobody wanted or ever suggested that.  You are wrong about the `(let ((x ...)) ...)` / `((lambda (x ...) ...) ...)` distinction: these are trivial source transforms in either direction, there is no additional analysis needed (early lisp compilers were dumb, but not *that* dumb).  Indeed `let` first arrived in maclisp as a macro which turned into the corresponding `lambda` form.

Comment: what I am trying to say is that having fewer special forms isn't necessarily a good thing because the remaining special forms get more complex. I stand corrected for let/lambda, thanks (I don't think anyone suggested anything about the empty let, it's the fact that it's horrible as a replacement for progn is the point)

Comment: The special treatment `progn` receives as a top-level form is the result of a process which is applied to `progn`, and not its own evaluation semantics.  The same treatment could be applied to it if it were a function call form. The spec would say something like "If a call to the `progn` function occurs as a top-level form, then each of the argument expressions is treated as a top-level form."

Comment: The existing answer nails it: `progn` can propagate all values of its last argument to its result value. A function call cannot; a function call will receive only the primary value of multiple-value argument.

Comment: @Kaz: *all* special forms get their semantics from the evaluator, not from their definition in terms of other operators: the behaviour of `progn` at top level is simply part of that semantics.  The argument you give in your second commend explains why `progn` cannot be a function: that's what was asked in the 'duplicate' question (which is not, of course, a duplicate, but never mind) but not what was asked here, which was why it can't be a macro defined in terms of `let`.  I think that other than top-level behaviour it could be in fact though I may have missed something else.